# Data label at horizontal bar graph like one at center and another one at right in tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I want to add one label at center and another one at right like below figure
in horizontal bar graph.

[image]

Comment: corrected the link to the image

Answer (score 2):

There is a workaround for that. 
Copy the measure you use a second time in the same shelf, you now have 2 identical graphs. Label one graph with the value you want and align it to the centre, label the other graph with the second measure and align it to the right.

If you now right click on one of the axis you can choose "dual axis" and "synchronise axis". You now have just one graph with labels at 2 different positions. In case you don't see the label in the centre you will have to right click on one of the axis and choose "bring to front"

Comment: You can also manually position individual labels by selecting and dragging them. Kind of a last resort, but good for putting finishing polish on a viz before publishing.

Comment: True, I always forget that it is possible. However that would only give you one label with 2 values to reposition right?

Comment: You get a label per mark. if you want two labels per row, you'll need to have two marks per row somehow. Either by a dual axis as in your answer, stacked bars or some other way. Manual repositioning can help fine tune label placement but won't create new labels. I suppose you could also add an a mark annotation per row to serve the place of a second label. Kind of labor intensive

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is to place the field you want as a center label on the label shelf in addition to the column shelf (with the label alignment set to center) and to place the field you want as an end label on the detail shelf.

The trick then is to create an invisible reference line that displays the end label. Create a reference line scoped to each cell positioned using the field on the column shelf, but customize the label for the reference line to show the field you placed on the detail shelf.

Format the reference line to have the line thickness None.

If you want position the reference line labels automatically a certain distance beyond the bars, you could create a calculated field to add a constant to the bar length.

I'm not sure this will lead to a very effective way to display measures that don't even share the same units of measure as in the example, but it does show that reference lines and bands can be used to get different effects.

Comment: Both this answer and the one below by @Alexander should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

Tableau by default will give you text either on the center or at the end of the bar chart.

Your concern is to show numbers at the location where it will not show by default.

You can create floating text boxes (can contain hard coded text or formulas) and place them on the bar chart with x and y co-ordinates.

Let me know if this helps.